# How to save Google Drive download outpustream to a file?

Tags: java, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

I want to download a file from my Google Drive Account and save it on my computer.

```
String fileId = "0BwwA4oUTeiV1UVNwOHItT0xfa2M";
OutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
service.files().get(fileId).executeMediaAndDownloadTo(outputStream);
```

I don't know how to handle the outpustream so I can export it to a file. The code I am using is from [Google Drive APIs](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code you have now gets the stream you just need to save it as a file.

```
OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("fileName");

DriveFiles.Get request = drive.files().get(fileId);
request.getMediaHttpDownloader().setProgressListener(new CustomProgressListener());
request.executeMediaAndDownloadTo(out);
```

You should be checking the documentation for the Google APIs Java client library [Resumable Media Downloads](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-api-java-client/media-download).

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved the day again!